# Alternative to property on function in Python?

Tags: python, functions

I have a collection of Python objects, lets call them fruits. Some of these fruits might be faulty. To check for these faults, I have a number of functions that performs different checks, and returns a list of fruits that did not pass the check:

```
def not_delicious(fruits, limit):
    return fruit for fruit in fruits if fruit.tastyness < limit

def not_ripe(fruits):
    return fruit for fruit in fruits if not fruit.ripe
```

Now I want to have a method that lets me neatly log the result of these checks. A naive approach looks like this:

```
def log_not_delicious(fruits, limit):
    for fruit in not_delicious(fruits, limit):
        log("The fruit {name} was not delicious enough.".format(**fruit))

def log_not_ripe(fruits):
    for fruit in not_ripe(fruits):
        log("The fruit {name} was not ripe.".format(**fruit))
```

Thats a lot of boilerplate. To simplify, I would like a function `log_check` that takes the check I want to perform as input, and then do the logging for me. So I can use it like this:

```
log_check(not_delicious, fruits, 7)
```

Such a function should not be so hard to write. Something along these lines:

```
def log_check(check, fruit, *args, **kwargs):
    for fruit in check(fruit, *args, **kwargs):
        log(message.format(**fruit))
```

There is only one problem. How does `log_check` know what `message` to use? I have thought of two solutions to this, but I like none of them:

1. Put it as a property on the `check` function, so I have e.g.:

   ```
   not_delicious.message = "The fruit {name} was not delicious enough."
   ```

   This doesn't feel very Pythonic - it feels more like JavaScript.
2. Use a class instead as a function for `check`. This feels a bit overkill - I have been thought that I only need to use a class if I have an internal state. And there's no state here - I perform the check, and then I am done.

Is there a third alternative, or what is my best approach here?

Comment: The proper place for the message string is as an argument to `log_check()`. This has nothing to do with Python, it's a general principle that business logic should not be intermingled with I/O.

Comment: @KilianFoth I want to avoid having to pass it as a parameter each time the function is used. That way, the place invoking the logging does not need to keep track of the message.

Comment: @KilianFoth both 1 & 2 are ways to (transitively) have the message as an argument

Comment: Explanations for down votes are always welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a job for polymorphism.

You want to bind checks and messages together without binding them to the `log_check` code. This is a good idea.

You're reluctant to use a class because the class would be stateless. To that I say: Feh!  Stateless objects are perfectly fine.

An object is a bag of functions that move around together. The state is just something that also changes the behavior of those functions together.

Stateless objects got a bad rep in OO because some goofballs thought stateless meant methods had to be static.  No, that's backwards.

```
log_check( fruits = fruits, ripe(), delicious(7) )
```

Any reason it shouldn't be that simple?

Answer (score 3):

If you e.g. don't want to rewrite a bunch of existing functions just to attach messages to them, you can do so externally:

```
CHECKS = {
  (check_ripeness, 'This ain\'t no ripe enough'),
  (check_taste, 'deliciousness does not conform to the standards'),
  # etc
}

# somewhere in your method
for (predicate, message) in CHECKS:
  if not predicate(fruit):
    log(message)
```

Using classes with a `__call__` would achieve the same result, just less straightforwardly.

Comment: @Anders: updated to use tuples. You apparently don't need to easily look up a specific check by name.

Answer (score 2):

Create an type that holds the message and the checker function. Use namedtuple or a class.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Check = namedtuple('Check', ('message', 'checker'))
```

Now, you can create objects that hold both the message and a function to check the fruit.

```
ripe = Check(message = "is not ripe", lambda fruit: fruit.tastiness < 5)
```

Then you write a generic function

```
def log_fruits(fruits, checker):
    for fruit in fruits:
        if checker(fruit):
            print("Fruit: ", fruit, checker.message)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a class. Behavior is also part of the state if you are using polymorphism, but in this case you may not even need "formal" polymorphism - just use one class for all checks, with the message and predicate as parameters.

Additionally:

- Since you are using a class, it may be a good idea to pass a predicate that checks a single fruit let the class handle the checking of a list of them.
- To make the syntax nicer, you can use a decorator.

So, I would have done something like this:

```
log = print


class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

# Single class, receives predicate as parameter
class Check(object):
    def __init__(self, predicate, message):
        self.predicate = predicate
        self.message = message

    def check(self, fruits, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Run the predicate on a list of checks """
        for fruit in fruits:
            if self.predicate(fruit, *args, **kwargs):
                yield fruit

    def log(self, fruits, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Check a list of fruits, logging the results """
        for fruit in self.check(fruits, *args, **kwargs):
            log(self.message.format(**fruit.__dict__))


def check(message):
    """ Helper decorator to ease the creationg of Check objects """
    def wrapper(func):
        return Check(func, message)
    return wrapper


@check(message="The fruit {name} was not delicious enough.")
def not_delicious(fruit, limit):
    return fruit.tastyness < limit


@check(message="The fruit {name} was not ripe")
def not_ripe(fruit):
    return not fruit.ripe


fruits = [Fruit("Yellow Banana", ripe=True, tastyness=10),
          Fruit("Green Banana", ripe=False, tastyness=0),
          Fruit("Grapefruit", ripe=True, tastyness=-float('inf'))]


not_delicious.log(fruits, limit=7)
not_ripe.log(fruits)
```